# select value from a div/script

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql, asp.net

i have an array with a lot of elements and with that im doing a dependent ddl of departments cities and districts

```
function showDepartamento(retValue, controlClass) {
    if (controlClass == null) { controlClass = ""; }; if (controlClass != "") { controlClass = "class=\"" + controlClass + "\" "; };
    var html = "<select name=\"ubigeoDep\" runat=\"server\" id=\"ubigeoDep\" class=\"form-control\" onchange=\"showProvincia(null,'');showDistrito(null,'');\" " + controlClass + ">";
    html += "<option value=\"\">Selecciona un departamento</option>";
    for (var i = 0; i < ubigeo.length; i++) {
        if ((ubigeo[i][1] == "00") && (ubigeo[i][2] == "00")) {
            html += "<option "; if (retValue == ubigeo[i][0]) { html += "selected "; }
            html += "value=\"" + ubigeo[i][0] + "\">" + ubigeo[i][3] + "</option>";
        }
    }
    html += "</select>";
    if (!document.getElementById("ubigeoDep_div")) { document.write("<div  id=\"ubigeoDep_div\"></div>"); }
    document.getElementById("ubigeoDep_div").innerText = html; html = null;

}
```

the ddl are being fill by this code in asp.net

```
<div class="row">  
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Departamento</label>
        <div id="ubigeoDep_div" runat="server"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">showDepartamento();</script>
        <p class="text-danger" id="DepV" value="Departamento requerido"></p>
</div>
</div>
```

but when i want to export to a sql db i cant get de value on string (im using C# for sql btw)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@departamento", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ubigeoDep_div.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@provincia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ubigeoPro_div.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@distrito", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ubigeoDis_div.ToString();
```

im using this but it dont give me the string i want and it apears in blank or System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl

Comment: Can you show us how you define `ubigeoDep_div, ubigeoPro_div, ubigeoDis_div`? I'm guessing these are the names of your dropdown controls. If that's the case, you can get the selected value with, for example, `ubigeoDep_div.SelectedItem.Value`, and then convert it to a string.

Comment: You cannot add runat=server as plain text to a control and expect it to work. It does not work like that. You need to add the control to the aspx or create dynamci controls if you want to access the values in code behind,